# Open/close div toggle and click outside div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This post looks like duplicate, but I think is not. Now you can click `Show box` and show red box, if you want close this box, click outside.

Question: How close this red box on click again `Show box` text except click outside. And how change css style after click e.g. change font-size `Show box` after click

```js
var myApplication = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApplication.directive('hideLogin', function($document){
  return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
   elem.bind('click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $document.bind('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(attr.hideLogin);
     })
    }
  }
});

myApplication.controller('hideContainer',function ($scope){
    $scope.openLogin = function(){
        $scope.userLogin = true;
   };
     $scope.hideLoginContainer = function(){
        $scope.userLogin = false;
   };
 });
```

```css
body {
    position:relative;
}

.loginBox {
    z-index:10; 
    background:red; 
    width:100px; 
    height:80px; 
    padding:10px; 
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="hideContainer">
  <a href="#" ng-click="openLogin()" hide-login="hideLoginContainer()">Show box</a>
  <div hide-login="hideLoginContainer()" class="loginBox" ng-show="userLogin" style="display:none;">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to hide the box on click on it, use `$scope.userLogin = !$scope.userLogin` condition.

To change it's css style, e.g. `font-size`, use `ng-class`. If `userLogin` variable is `true`, it will add `fontSize` class into it, changing it's `font-size`.

```js
var myApplication = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApplication.directive('hideLogin', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      elem.bind('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      });
      $document.bind('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(attr.hideLogin);
      })
    }
  }
});

myApplication.controller('hideContainer', function($scope) {
  $scope.openLogin = function() {
    $scope.userLogin = !$scope.userLogin;
  };
  $scope.hideLoginContainer = function() {
    $scope.userLogin = false;
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.loginBox {
  z-index: 10;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.fontSize {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="hideContainer">
  <a href="#" ng-click="openLogin()" hide-login="hideLoginContainer()"  ng-class="{'fontSize': userLogin}">Show box</a>
  <div hide-login="hideLoginContainer()" class="loginBox" ng-show="userLogin" style="display:none;">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: could explain me why this script works on Angular 1.0.2 but on newer nor e.g. Angular 1.2.23?

Comment: @V.R Will check it out.

Comment: @V.R I've checked it in Angular 1.3x and it works. I have made a plunker for you: https://plnkr.co/edit/UX7eGy0DwmoS3FdXjrIv

Comment: Thank you for time and help

Answer (score 1):

instead of using multiple `$scope` for achieve something like this you can use a single `$scope` variable, take look at code snippet.

```js
var myApplication = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApplication.directive('hideLogin', function($document){
  return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
   elem.bind('click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $document.bind('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(attr.hideLogin);
     })
    }
  }
});

myApplication.controller('hideContainer',function ($scope){
     $scope.userLogin = true;
     $scope.hideLoginContainer = function(){
        $scope.userLogin = true;
    };
 });
```

```css
body
{
position:relative;
}
.loginBox
{
z-index:10; 
background:red; 
width:100px; 
height:80px; 
padding:10px; 
position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="hideContainer">
  <a href="#" ng-click="userLogin = !userLogin" hide-login="hideLoginContainer()">Show box</a>
  <div hide-login="hideLoginContainer()" class="loginBox" ng-show="!userLogin" style="display:none;">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think OP wanted to also keep functionality of hiding the box when clicking anywhere outside.

Comment: @Fran ahhhh, I missed that

Answer (score 0):

You could rename `openLogin()` to `toggleLogin()` and change the function accordingly to

```
 $scope.toggleLogin = function(){
        $scope.userLogin != $scope.userLogin;
    };
```

That will toggle the box when you click on the link.

For the CSS part, use `ng-class` to conditionaly sign a class to the element if `userLogin ==true`

```
<div ng-class="{'myConditionalClass':userLogin }"></div>
```